# How Do I Correct GRUB2 Hanging On Boot?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, opensuse

> EDIT: Since posting this, I have noticed that I can boot openSUSE just fine when I insert the installation DVD, select "Boot From Hard Disk" and then boot the system. I do not know why.

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-B5353 with Linux openSUSE Tumbleweed. I recently noticed a problem with the GRUB2 boot loader that is affecting my system's ability to start.
When attempting to start the system, I typically encounter one of these errors:

1. Upon selecting "openSUSE Tumbleweed" from the boot menu, GRUB hangs after displaying the `Loading Initial Ramdisk ...` message. Instead of booting into the kernel, GRUB simply freezes, requiring me to forcibly shut down the system.
2. GRUB does not boot at all, instead freezing on the Toshiba splash screen.

When booting the kernel's rescue mode, the system sometimes boots, but more often, it hangs after going through the usual startup messages, and does not load the command prompt nor KDE. This problem sometimes occurs with single-user mode as booted through the installation DVD, although not as frequently.

Keep in mind:

- My system reports that it uses an Intel graphics card, which I presume indicates that graphics are run through the CPU. (APU?)
- I have not modified GRUB in any way since its installation.
- I have checked the openSUSE DVD and it appears to be free of corruption.
- My computer and openSUSE are configured to boot in UEFI mode. Secure boot is also enabled, but disabling this does not appear to affect the system's ability to boot.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Freezing could also be a hardware problem, e.g. RAM, or failure to attempt to initialize some other piece of hardware. Same for the partially working boots in rescue mode: As soon as the bad RAM gets used, problems happen. Systemd boot means the boot timing is not always identical, hence it freezes and different stages.